# Требуется ли в данном предложении запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Я понял больше чем на уроке. Если ставится, то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требуется запятая. Сравниваются 2 понятия:

Где-то понял больше. / На уроке понял меньше.

Похожий пример:

*Он съел больше, чем требовалось.*

(НЕ) БОЛЕЕ / БОЛЬШЕ, ЧЕМ *в составе сравнительного оборота*

Обороты, присоединяемые союзом «чем», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми, если в предложении называются или подразумеваются два сравниваемых понятия.

*Шут необходим толпе **более, чем** герой.* М. Горький, Жизнь Клима Самгина. *Кстати, вы, кажется, пострадали **более, чем** Билль.* А. Грин, Джесси и Моргиана. *Есть вещи, которые утомляют человека гораздо **более, чем** сама работа.* Л. Улицкая, Пиковая дама. *Милый зверь накуролесил на новом месте еще **больше, чем** у меня.* Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Мeдведко. *Вот Додик мой милый, милый и такой умный, он вырастет еще **больше, чем** ты.* Л. Андреев, Великан. *Поэт в России – **больше, чем** поэт…* Е. Евтушенко, Молитва перед поэмой. *Разбитое на мелкие осколки знание интересовало людей не **более, чем** всякая другая работа, в которой не видишь смысла и цели.* И. Ефремов, Час быка. *…Есть люди… которые смыслят в музыке **не больше, чем** некоторые животные…* М. Булгаков, Театральный роман. *…Седины у него **не больше, чем** у меня.* А. Битов, Рассеянный свет.

Однако при отсутствии сравниваемых понятий слова «(не) более / больше чем» образуют с последующими словами неразложимое сочетание (единый член предложения), не требующее постановки знаков препинания. Как правило, в этом случае после слов «(не) более / больше чем» следует количественно-именное сочетание (счетный оборот) или название единицы измерения (час, грамм, километр и т. п.).

*Таким образом тайна была сохранена **более чем** полудюжиною заговорщиков.* А. Пушкин, Метель. *Водка была горькая, разведенная, по случаю праздника, водой **более чем** на три четверти.* В. Короленко, Сон Макара. *Егоров вообще не любил, когда начальник розыскного отдела отлучался **более чем** на сутки…* В. Богомолов, Момент истины. *На снимке **более чем** столетней давности был изображен коллектив только что открывшегося мясного храма.* В. Аксенов, Новый сладостный стиль. *Деревня была уже **не более чем** в двухстах шагах…* Н. Гумилев, Записки кавалериста. *Совершенно больной и даже постаревший поэт **не более чем** через две минуты входил на веранду Грибоедова.* М. Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита. *Это разговор **не больше чем** на двадцать минут…* В. Аксенов, Новый сладостный стиль.